# Возможно ли как-то отмерять время выполнения кода, не учитывая ввод?

Tags: c++

Мне нужно сравнить кто быстрее будет работать: cin или

```
void fastscan(int& number)
{
    //variable to indicate sign of input number
    bool negative = false;
    register int c;

    number = 0;

    // extract current character from buffer
    c = getchar();
 
    if (c == '-')
    {
        // number is negative
        negative = true;

        // extract the next character from the buffer
        c = getchar();
    }

    // Keep on extracting characters if they are integers
    // i.e ASCII Value lies from '0'(48) to '9' (57)
    for (; (c > 47 && c < 58); c = getchar())
        number = number * 10 + c - 48;

    // if scanned input has a negative sign, negate the
    // value of the input number
    if (negative)
        number *= -1;
   
}
```

Есть ли способ как это сделать правильно?

Comment: если посмотреть на `register int c;` то уже очевидно, что Ваш пример устарел морально. Какая цель этой оптимизации?

Comment: Если это учебная задача, то особо напрягаться на счет скорости ввода не стоит.

Comment: ну тут такое. можно так накосячить, что работать будет еле-еле.

Comment: Как вариант, используйте [перенаправление ввода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0), чтобы связать поток ввода с файлом, а не консолью. Тогда для ввода чисел не потребуется вводить их вручную. Что позволит протестировать разные способы ввода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По моему вы хотите это:

```
void fastscan(int& number)
{
    if (cin.peek() == '-')
        cin.ignore();
    cin >> number;
    //по хорошему нужна еще и  проверка
    //с последующим приведением в состояние good
    if (cin.fail()) {
       // сообщить об ошибке "это не число"
       cin.clear();
    }
}
```

Сравнивание и расчеты всегда требуют время. Без замеров можно уверенно сказать, что так будет быстрее и понятнее. Сравнивать время при вводе для такой тривиальной функции затруднительно, связанное с работой операционной системы.

Comment: `Без замеров можно уверенно сказать, что так будет быстрее` Нет, без замеров нельзя быть уверенным, что так будет быстрее.